# User defaults, append the number entered each time a user submits a button

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to append something to an array each time the user presses a button and save it as a UserDefault.

I can save my text field as a user default based on what the user enters, but I am having trouble getting it saved and appended to my array.

```
import UIKit

var nums = ["3","4","5"]

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!

    @IBAction func submit_button(_ sender: Any) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(text.text!, forKey: "Submitted")
        // append
        nums.append("\(String(describing: text))")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let savedscore = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Submitted")
        if let saving = savedscore as?
            String{text.text = saving}

    }


}
```

I am trying to have my array grow each time someone submits in the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved your code and resolved your issue. so, please go ahead and check below code and share your review in comment.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var nums = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func submit_button(_ sender: Any) {

        if let text = textField.text {

            // Append to array
            nums.append("\(text)")

            // Save to User Defaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(nums, forKey: "NumberOfArray")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(textField.text, forKey: "Submitted")

            // Refresh User Defaults
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }

        // Print Updated Data
        print("numbers: \(nums)")
        print("text: \(textField.text ?? "")")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let savedscore = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Submitted")

        if let saving = savedscore as? String
        {
            textField.text = saving
        }

        // Update Array Based on userdefault data.
        nums = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "NumberOfArray") as? [String] ?? []

        // Print Saved Data
        print("numbers: \(nums)")
        print("text: \(textField.text ?? "")")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to delete a specific entry in my array that is saved and have it update?

Comment: Yes, you can filter the saved `nums` array and delete or update that value

Answer (score 0):

**For last value**

Save

```
let str = text.text!  
UserDefaults.standard.set(str, forKey: "Submitted") 
nums.append(str)
```

Read

```
if let savedscore = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Submitted") {
   self.text.text =  savedscore  
}
```

**For the array**

Save

```
let str = text.text!  
nums.append(str) 
UserDefaults.standard.set(nums, forKey: "Submitted")
```

Read

```
if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "Submitted") as? [String] {
   print(arr)
   // set first value or what you need
   self.text.text =  arr.first  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the array after appending the text in button action

```
@IBAction func submit_button(_ sender: Any) {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(text.text!, forKey: "Submitted")
    // append
    nums.append("\(String(describing: text.text!))")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(nums, forKey: "nums")
}
```

And to get the value use

```
if let nums = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "nums") as? [String] {
    print(nums)
}
```

---

Or you can use computed property with property observer to save the array in UserDefaults automatically when a new value is appended.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var nums: [String] {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayValue") as? [String] ?? []
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "arrayValue")
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
    @IBAction func submit_button(_ sender: Any) {
        nums.append(text.text!)//Array updated in UserDefaults automatically
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.nums)//Array fetched from UserDefaults
    }
}
```